# Paginate a Firebase query by timestamp

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say that I want to retrieve posts with the following structure, paginated, ordered by the timestamp:

```
post_key: {
    message: "message"
    timestamp: 1234567890
}
```

I can use `.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: 5)...` for the initial fetch. But for the second fetch, there is a problem if the last timestamp from the previous fetch has duplicates.

I have to somehow order by `timestamp` and end at a key. Something like:

```
.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atPOSTkey: lastPostKey)
```

Any ideas how to solve this? One way I thought of is to concatenate the timestamp with the post key but I think there is an easier solution (I saw that there is function `queryEnding(atValue, childKey)` but can't really seem to make it work).

---

**Edit 1:**

I think I managed to make it work as follows: `ref.child("posts/byLocation/\(userLocation)/\(dashedInterests)").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: lastTimestamp, childKey: lastPostKey).queryLimited(toLast: postsPerPage + 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) ...`

The problem is that now I always get this warning:

> Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered
>   on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "timestamp" at
>   /posts/byLocation/1/1-2-3 to your security rules for better
>   performance.

I can't really add the .indexOn rule as I have several nodes like `1-2-3` which are dynamically generated (for example 1, 2, 3, 1-2, 1-3 etc.)

---

**Edit 2:**

I added the following rules:

```
"posts": {
        "$dashed_interests": {
            ".indexOn": "timestamp"
        },
      "byLocation": {
        "1": {
          "$dashed_interests": {
            ".indexOn": "timestamp"
            } 
      }
}
```

and I stopped getting the warning.

If someone can confirm that what I did is good, it would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work as follows: `ref.child("posts/byLocation/\(userLocation)/\(dashedInterests)").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: lastTimestamp, childKey: lastPostKey).queryLimited(toLast: postsPerPage + 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) ...` where lastPostKey and lastTimestamp are the last key and timestamp from the previous fetch.

There would be one more problem as I always get this warning:

> Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered
>   on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "timestamp" at
>   /posts/byLocation/1/1-2-3 to your security rules for better
>   performance.

As I have several nodes like 1-2-3 which are dynamically generated (for example 1, 2, 3, 1-2, 1-3 etc.), I solved it by adding the following rule:

```
"posts":{
        "byLocation":{
           "$location":{
              "$dashed_interests":{
                 ".indexOn":"timestamp"
              }
           }
        }
...
```